# How to create a json string where a property contains a dot (period)?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to send an `HttpRequest` that takes a JSON object like this:

```
{
   "some.setting.withperiods":"myvalue"
}
```

I've been creating anonymous objects for my other requests, but I can't do that with this one since the name contains a dot.

I know I can create a class and specify the `[DataMember(Name="some.setting.withperiods")]` attribute, but there must be a more lightweight solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "easy" way to achieve this because the `.` in C# is reserved.

However, you could achieve something pretty close by using a dictionary and collection initializer. It's still somewhat isolated, and doesn't require you to create a custom class.

```
var obj = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "some.setting.withperiods", "myvalue" }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
//{"some.setting.withperiods":"myvalue"}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!  Having the value type of the Dictionary be an object makes it usable for all my other properties I need to add.

Answer (score 5):

You can use "JsonProperty" attribute for the same For example

```
    [JsonProperty(".Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: The OP said in the question that he knows he can use attributes but is looking for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

On top of this I want to add how to retrieve the data from the json where it has name property starting with special character as in Web API 2.0 token has ".issued".

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
var jsonRespons="json response from the web api";
var issue= JObject.Parse(jsonResponse).GetValue(".issued");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do it from in javascript, you can easily go back and forth, as shown with:

```
var obj = {
    "some.setting.withdots":"myvalue"
};
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json);
var str = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(str);
```

have you tried putting it into a serialized string and sending that, then deserializing on the client-side?

you could do something like

```
var myAnnon = new
{
    WithPeriod = "value"
};
var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myAnnon);
j = j.Replace("WithPeriod", "some.setting.withdots");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JObject` (part of Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)) to create the JSON in question:

```
string json = new JObject(new JProperty("some.setting.withperiods", "myvalue")).ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bhgTta

Answer (score -1):

You could *try* prefixing your member names with a `@` to allow use of literals, but the way to do it is using `[DataMember]` as you have already mentioned in your question.

Comment: `@` still doesn't allow for `.` - it just allows for reserved keywords to be used