# Reading Json output from Odata services

Tags: c#, json, wcf, c#-4.0, odata

I am trying to read the output from odata services in json format. but i am getting the error message as

***"The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom or JSON element or belongs to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' namespace".***

```
NorthwindEntities dc = new NorthwindEntities(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/"),DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3);
        dc.Format.UseJson(new EdmModel());
        DataServiceQuery<Product> query = (DataServiceQuery<Product>)from o in dc.Products
            where o.UnitPrice > 0
            select o; query.execute();


{"odata.metadata":"http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata#Products","value":[{"ProductID":24,"ProductName":"Guaran\u00e1 Fant\u00e1stica","SupplierID":10,"CategoryID":1,"QuantityPerUnit":"12 - 355 ml cans","UnitPrice":"4.5000","UnitsInStock":20,"UnitsOnOrder":0,"ReorderLevel":0,"Discontinued":true},{"ProductID":33,"ProductName":"Geitost","SupplierID":15,"CategoryID":4,"QuantityPerUnit":"500 g","UnitPrice":"2.5000","UnitsInStock":112,"UnitsOnOrder":0,"ReorderLevel":20,"Discontinued":false}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You JSON string is not valid as it has a property name with a '.' in it.
odata.metadata cannot be resolved.

If you changed that to odata_metadata, or possible went with the solution provided here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121025/how-to-create-a-json-string-where-a-property-contains-a-dot-period)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i have set the odata format to Nometadata still i am getting the same error. And the current Output is `{"value":[{"ProductID":33,"ProductName":"Geitost","SupplierID":15,"CategoryID":4,"QuantityPerUnit":"500 g","UnitPrice":"2.5000","UnitsInStock":112,"UnitsOnOrder":0,"ReorderLevel":20,"Discontinued":false}]}` @travisco_nabisco